# R - Counting through a vector and refreshing at a certain value?

Tags: r, vector

Let's say I have a vector

```
vec <- c(3,0,1,1,0,3,0,1,3,0,0,0,3)
```

And I want to be able to count through this vector using the value 3 as the refresh point. So, the output I want is

```
       vec   out
 [1,]    3    1
 [2,]    0    2
 [3,]    1    3
 [4,]    1    4
 [5,]    0    5
 [6,]    3    1
 [7,]    0    2
 [8,]    1    3
 [9,]    3    1
[10,]    0    2
[11,]    0    3
[12,]    0    4
[13,]    3    1
```

How would I do this in R, preferably without using loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option using `data.table::rowid`:

```
data.table::rowid(cumsum(vec==3L))
```

Answer (score 4):

With `base R`, you can do:

```
ave(vec, cumsum(vec == 3), FUN = seq_along)

 [1] 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 1
```

Answer (score 2):

As another idea, we can locate the indices of the last value of 3 for each element of `vec`:

```
last3 = cummax((vec == 3) * seq_along(vec))
last3
# [1]  1  1  1  1  1  6  6  6  9  9  9  9 13
```

And subtract from their respective indices in `vec`:

```
seq_along(vec) - last3 + 1   ## `.. - pmax(last3, 1) ..` if `vec[1] != 3`
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 1
```